# Как это работает? Пример TDLib с шаблонами на C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Не могу до конца сообразить как работает данная конструкция в примере использования библиотеки TDLib. [сам пример](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/cpp/td_example.cpp).
Итак, в начале создаются вот такие шаблонные классы и функция для возможности передачи нескольких функций обработчику.

```
namespace detail {
template <class... Fs>
struct overload;

template <class F>
struct overload<F> : public F {
  explicit overload(F f) : F(f) {
  }
};
template <class F, class... Fs>
struct overload<F, Fs...>
    : public overload<F>
    , overload<Fs...> {
  overload(F f, Fs... fs) : overload<F>(f), overload<Fs...>(fs...) {
  }
  using overload<F>::operator();
  using overload<Fs...>::operator();
};
}  // namespace detail

template <class... F>
auto overloaded(F... f) {
  return detail::overload<F...>(f...);
}
```

А потом вызывается сам обработчик для некоего объекта:

```
td_api::downcast_call(
    *update, overloaded(
                 [this](td_api::updateAuthorizationState &update_authorization_state) {
                   authorization_state_ = std::move(update_authorization_state.authorization_state_);
                   on_authorization_state_update();
                 },
                 [this](td_api::updateNewChat &update_new_chat) {
                   chat_title_[update_new_chat.chat_->id_] = update_new_chat.chat_->title_;
                 },
                 [this](td_api::updateChatTitle &update_chat_title) {
                   chat_title_[update_chat_title.chat_id_] = update_chat_title.title_;
                 },
                 [this](td_api::updateUser &update_user) {
                   auto user_id = update_user.user_->id_;
                   users_[user_id] = std::move(update_user.user_);
                 },
                 [this](td_api::updateNewMessage &update_new_message) {
                   auto chat_id = update_new_message.message_->chat_id_;
                   auto sender_user_name = get_user_name(update_new_message.message_->sender_user_id_);
                   std::string text;
                   if (update_new_message.message_->content_->get_id() == td_api::messageText::ID) {
                     text = static_cast<td_api::messageText &>(*update_new_message.message_->content_).text_->text_;
                   }
                   std::cerr << "Got message: [chat_id:" << chat_id << "] [from:" << sender_user_name << "] ["
                             << text << "]" << std::endl;
                 },
                 [](auto &update) {}));
```

сама `td_api::downcast_call` простая, она выясняет тип объекта, и передает его в `func`.

```
bool downcast_call(AuthorizationState &obj, const T &func) {
   switch (obj.get_id()) {
     case authorizationStateWaitTdlibParameters::ID:
       func(static_cast<authorizationStateWaitTdlibParameters &>(obj));
       return true;
     case authorizationStateWaitEncryptionKey::ID:
       func(static_cast<authorizationStateWaitEncryptionKey &>(obj));
       return true;
```

мне не очень понятно, как работает функция `overloaded` и как выясняется какую именно лямбду вызывать в `td_api::downcast_call`. `overloaded`, видимо, создает в итоге вложенную друг в друга кучу объектов `struct overload<F, Fs...>, struct overload<F>` и так как мы указали, что используем `operator()` базового класса, то при вызове `func`компилятор находит подходящий `operator()` для вызова. Если не так, то поправьте меня пожалуйста. И вообще, есть ли название у такого подхода? Можно ли где-то найти его описание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специализация класса `overload` со множеством параметров наследует от пачки специализаций класса `overload` с одним параметром. Каждый из этих базовых классов наследует от анонимного класса, созданного лямбда-выражением и имеет оператор `()` с сигнатурой как у того лямбда-выражения. Затем все перегруженные операторы `()` из базовых классов переносятся в наследующий класс посредством директив `using overload<F>::operator(); using overload<Fs...>::operator();`. Этот шаг принципиально важен, так как компилятор может выбирать из перегруженных функций, относящихся только к одному классу.

Таким образом, в результате получается специализация класса `overload` c набором перегрузок, соответствующим сигнатурам переданных лямбд.

Comment: спасибо. то есть using overload<F>::operator(); using overload<Fs...>::operator(); означает, что мы хотим использовать все перегрузки operator() как от первого базового класса overload<F> так и от второго базового класса overload<Fs...>? И еще, это какой-то стандартный подход для реализации подобного функционала? Есть ли у него описание или название?

Comment: @bronstein87 Да, иначе при вызове оператора `()` была бы ошибка, что имя `operator ()` не является однозначным. По мне это хардкорная перверсия...

Comment: А в чем смысл добавлять прослойку из специализаций с 1 параметром? Есть какая-то причина не наследоваться сразу от лямбд?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Можно было бы наследовать сразу от лямбд, но тогда бы пришлось писать `public: using F::operator()...;`, а такая конструкция доступна начиная с С++17, в то время как библиотека С++14.